# How can we parse multiline using pyspark

Tags: hive, pyspark

I am having a test csv file with below content:

"TVBQGEM461
2016-10-05 14:04:33 cvisser gefixt door company
"

I need to store this entire content into one single row. However while processing with pyspark, this are getting splitted into 2 rows.

Below is the pyspark code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

customSchema = StructType([ \
    StructField("desc", StringType(), True)])

df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false', inferschema='true').load('/dev/landingzone/test.csv', schema = customSchema)

df.registerTempTable("temp")
sqlContext.sql("create table dev_core_source.test as select * from temp")
```

Data is getting loaded into the hive table, but they are splited into 2 rows instead of 1 row

I have also tried some other options like the one below for creating data frame, but still facing the same issue.

```
df = sqlContext.read \
...          .format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
...          .options(header='true') \
...          .option(inferschema, 'true') \
...          .option(wholeFile, 'true') \
...          .options(parserLib ='UNIVOCITY') \
...          .load('/dev/landingzone/test.csv', schema = customSchema)
```

Comment: Have u tried .repartition(1)? With CSV I suggest always to use RDD firstly and pass it to DF

Comment: yes, but if we are using com.databricks.spark.csv, then it gives the option of dataframe

Comment: ‘sc.textFile(“pathfile”).map(lambda x: x.split(“,”))’ is the same for RDD

Comment: I tried with rdd, but there also when I do collect, I can see two rows being created instaed on one row.